# Waiting certain amount of time with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a Tkinter program which I want to pause for 3 seconds.
`time.sleep` doesn't work and the `after` method doesn't do exactly what I want to.

here is an example code:

```
from Tkinter import *
def waithere():
    print "waiting..."
root = Tk()

print "1"
root.after(3000,waithere)
print "2"

root.mainloop()
```

output:

```
1
2
*3 seconds*
waiting...
```

the output i want to have:

```
1
waiting...
*3 seconds*
2
```

thanks.

Comment: What's the point of pausing? Is that really what you need to do, or are you just thinking that a pause is similar to what you really want to do? In other words, do you actually want the GUI to pause, or do you just want something to happen in three seconds? Your little example program is simply not  how tkinter is designed to work.

Comment: @BryanOakley I want the program to do something after waiting 3 seconds.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. Why do you need to _wait_? You already know how to use `after`, so why not just use `after` for the other things you want to happen in the future, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it's a very bad idea to have a GUI wait for something. That's imply not how event-based programs work. Or more accurately, GUIs are already in a perpetual wait state, and you don't want to block that with your own waiting.

That being said, tkinter has a way to wait until certain things happen. For example, you can use one of the "wait" functions, such as [wait_variable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_variable-method), [wait_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_window-method), or [wait_visibility](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_visibility-method).

Assuming that you wanted `waithere` to do the waiting, you could use [wait_variable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_variable-method) to do the waiting, and `after` to set the variable after a given amount of time.

Here's the solution based on your original code:

```
from Tkinter import *
def waithere():
    var = IntVar()
    root.after(3000, var.set, 1)
    print("waiting...")
    root.wait_variable(var)

root = Tk()

print "1"
waithere()
print "2"

root.mainloop()
```

The advantage to using these methods is that your code is still able to respond to events while it is waiting.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way like that, i hope it helps you:

```
from tkinter import *

def waitToShow():
    index = 1
    while index < 11:
        l1.config(text=index)
        l1.after(1000)
        l1.update()
        index += 1

win = Tk()
l1 = Label(win)
l1.pack()

waitToShow()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, refrain from using long or infinite loops in `Tkinter`; they will prevent the UI from responding to user events (AKA freezing). The method I was taught was to periodically update the field using the `after()` function.

The [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) function creates an alarm-callback meaning when called (with the right parameters) it will queue a call to the target method (in the example below `def update(self)` with our entered delay. You can use a boolean in the class to exit the loop. Create on on `__init__` and then when set to `False` don't call `after()` anymore.

Here is an example creating a class inheriting Tkinter.Frame to inherit the functionality.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

import datetime


class DelayedUpdateUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        # Create widgets, if any.
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.timeStr = tk.StringVar()
        self.lblTime = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.timeStr)
        self.lblTime.grid()
        # Call update to begin our recursive loop.
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.timeStr.set(datetime.datetime.now())
        # We use after( milliseconds, method_target ) to call our update
        # method again after our entered delay. :)
        self.after(1000, self.update)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    DelayedUpdateUI(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question tho

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question but it gives you the information necessary to do what you want. Is there anything confusing about it? I'm more than willing to answer questions.

Comment: yes It's very confusing.
I would glad if you can maybe show me how it's possible to make a program to output
`1
waiting...
*3 seconds*
2` that way.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology. What tkinter does with `after` is not "threading" in any sense of the word. Tkinter is single threaded, even when using `after`.

Comment: recursion going to cause problems long term?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion based on [Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51770561/12646289):

I understand the recommended way from an event-based perspective, but it does not feel very intuitive to me. I have to look up the trick every time I need it. Therefore, I have created a small mixin class that makes usage a bit more intuitive:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class TkWaitMixin:
    """Simple wait timer that makes Tk waiting functionality 
    more intiutive. Applies the recommended way according to
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/51770561/12646289.
    """
    def start_wait_timer(self, milliseconds):
        self.resume = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
        self.master.after(milliseconds, self.resume.set, True)
        # Assume master attribute is available: 
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595036/12646289
        
    def wait_on_timer(self):
        self.master.wait_variable(self.resume)
```

Example usage:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow(tk.Tk, TkWaitMixin):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.message_label = tk.Label('')
        self.message_label.pack(padx=50, pady=50)
        
    def show_message(self, message, milliseconds):
        self.start_wait_timer(milliseconds)
        self.message_label['text'] = message
        self.wait_on_timer()
        self.message_label['text'] = ''
        
root = tk.Tk()
mywin = MyWindow(master=root)
mywin.show_message('Hello world', 2000)
root.mainloop()
```

Obviously, this will only be of use if you use classes in your tkinter code. Also note that the `master` attribute should be available in the main class to which the mixin is added.

### Edit

---

Alternatively, usage can be made even easier with a context manager:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class TkWait:
    def __init__(self, master, milliseconds):
        self.duration = milliseconds
        self.master = master
        
    def __enter__(self):
        self.resume = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.master.after(self.duration, self.resume.set, True)
        self.master.wait_variable(self.resume)
```

Note that the waiting starts when the context manager is exited.

Example usage:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.message_label = tk.Label('')
        self.message_label.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

    def show_message(self, message, milliseconds):
        with TkWait(self.master, milliseconds):
            self.message_label['text'] = message
        self.message_label['text'] = ''

root = tk.Tk()
mywin = MyWindow(master=root)
mywin.show_message('Hello world', 2000)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do the () at `root.after(3000,waithere <<<<-)`

```
from tkinter import *

def waithere():
    print("waiting...")
root = Tk()

print("1")
root.after(3000,waithere())
print("2")

root.mainloop()
```